# Macro to load multiple root files

Tags: c++, root-framework

I have some code that loads in a ROOT file from which I can extract branches from said ROOT file and plot histograms, etc. The code looks something like this:

```
void MakePlots(string filename) {
    TChain Data("clusters");
    Data.Add(filename.c_str());

    Double_t rr, rx, ry, rz, rrho, rtheta, rphi;

    Data.SetBranchAddress("laben.recon.r", &rr);
    Data.SetBranchAddress("laben.recon.rho", &rrho);
    Data.SetBranchAddress("laben.recon.latitude", &rtheta);
    Data.SetBranchAddress("laben.recon.longitude", &rphi);
    Data.SetBranchAddress("laben.recon.z", &rz);
    Data.SetBranchAddress("laben.recon.y", &ry);
    Data.SetBranchAddress("laben.recon.x", &rx);

    int NumEvents = Data.GetEntries();

    for(int event = 0; event < NumEvents; event++) {
        if(event % 1000 == 0) cout << "Processing Event " << event << endl;
        Data.GetEvent(event);
    }
}
```

This works fine and dandy for just loading in one file and making plots from that file. However, I would like to load in n files and do the same operations. More specifically, if I have a directory filled with all the ROOT files I want to load, can I write a program that will load each file from that directory. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you load multiple files using a repeated call of Data.Add(...):

```
Data.Add("file1.root");
Data.Add("file2.root");
...

Data.Add("fileN.root");
```

Then you should call:

```
Data.GetEntries();
```

Which initializes the TChain. After that you set the Branch addresses, etc. NOTE:
When you call:

```
TChain Data("clusters");
```

the parameter "clusters" is the TTree name and that has to be the same in all files you add.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Asen Christov. I am still having trouble figuring out how to simply just add every file from a directory. The method above works well if I manually insert filenames into code but what I am trying to do is just pull out every file from directory.

Comment: Two advices:First, if you search for "how to get a list of files in a directory" you'll find the answer. Second, using ROOT from python (pyroot: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/pyroot ) makes life much easier, for instance getting list of files in a directory is trivial.